# How to trigger an airflow dag via API written in nodejs

Tags: node.js, airflow, airflow-webserver

As I'm new to Apache Airflow, Can someone please tell how to trigger, update an airflow dag using API call.

Comment: There are plenty of airflow docs on how to do this, including API documentation.

Comment: What you want to update in Airflow dag?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow offers a [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html). You can trigger a dag run using the [`/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns` endpoint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run).

I'm not sure what you mean by "update an airflow dag using api call". [Airflow updates DAGs according to the source files in the `DAGS_FOLDER`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#loading-dags).

Answer (score 0):

Airflow has rest API endpoints, which can be used in your node js app

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/rest-api-ref.html

Here is the video tutorial as well

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTR-YT5imrY